# Change value of an element in a LinkedList in java

Tags: java, list, pointers, linked-list, listiterator

I defined a linked list of `Candidate` objects. I need to store the initial next element for every element (since I would be changing the order later, and require the initial order).

```
public class Candidate {
    //data members
    private String prefrence;
    private Candidate next;
    public void setNext(Candidate c){ next=c; }
    //rest of the class body
}
```

In a separate class I need to create a list of candidates (`candidateList`) where I have to initialize it,

```
while(input) {
    Candidate c = new Candidate(field[0], field[1], field[2], ...);
    candidateList.add(c);
}
```

Now, I need to store the next element of list in `c.next`. I also require to iterate over the entire list and change the preference of candidate in list. However, I don't know how to access the elements of the list.

Basically, I know the c++ equivalent where pointer to `Candidate` (ptr), `ptr->datamember=abc;` would do the job. But I am new to Java and can't get the hang of pointer mechanism here. I intend something like this:

```
ListIterator<Candidate> itr = candidateList.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Candidate c = itr.next(); //I am supposing this creates a copy while i need a reference
    func(c.pref);
    c.pref = abc;
    c.next = def;
}
```

In short, I need to change the value of elements in a linked list and not change the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

`itr.next()` of `ListIterator` of `LinkedList` doesn't create a copy.

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    if (nextIndex == size)
    throw new NoSuchElementException();

    lastReturned = next;
    next = next.next;
    nextIndex++;
    return lastReturned.element;
}
```

It returns a reference to a `Candidate` object stored in the list. Therefore you can update the returned `Candidate`, which would update the `Candidate` object in the list.

Comment: oh thanks! But then if I need a copy of an object (so that I can change its value, without disturbing the original one), how do I obtain that

Comment: @code_enthu If you need a copy, you'll have to create the copy yourself, by implementing and calling a copy constructor or a clone() method in your Candidate class.